# PHP error in For loop

Tags: php

The code works fine but im getting the below error:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kwame.php on line 8

Can someone explain why this is so. Thank you.

```
<?

$string ='Lt4';
$getl = strlen($string);

for($i=0; $i<=$getl; $i++){

echo $string[$i];
}

?>
```

Comment: It should be `$i<$getl` and not `$i<=$getl`.

Comment: Character 'L' in your string represents index 0 and the character '4' represents index 2, but your for loop goes up to index 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the string doesn't have so many indexes! The index starts with 0. Just change `<=` to `<` Like this:

```
<?php

    $string = "Lt4";
             //^^^-Index 2
             //||-Index 1
             //|-Index 0

    $getl = strlen($string);  //Length: 3

    for($i = 0; $i < $getl; $i++) {  //i -> 0, 1, 2 
        echo $string[$i];  //L, t, 4            
    }

?>
```

Iteration Overview:

```
                  Variables            Condition                 Output 

              |  $i  |  $getl    |    $i < $getl  = ?     |    $string[$i] 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start:        |  0   |    3      |     
Iteration  1: |  0   |    3      |     0 < 3      = TRUE  |         L (Index 0)
Iteration  2: |  1   |    3      |     1 < 3      = TRUE  |         t (Index 1)
Iteration  3: |  2   |    3      |     2 < 3      = TRUE  |         4 (Index 2)
Iteration  4: |  3   |    3      |     3 < 3      = FALSE |      [OFFSET]
              |      |           |                        |
End           |  3   |    3      |                        |
              |      |           |                        |
```

Output:

```
Lt4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string ='Lt4';
$getl = strlen($string);
for($i=0; $i<$getl; $i++){
echo $string[$i];
}
?>
```

[image]

index always start from 0